# How to compare the current row to the rest of the rows in an analytical SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

SQL - Question with Oracle 19c:

I run over a dataset with an analytical function (with partition by, without ordering). For each row, I would like to compare the current row with the rest of the rows withing the group and in case I have a match, I would for example count how many matches I have.

I would expect something like this (how often is the same data avaiable in the group):

```
sum(case when current_row.dt = row.dt then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by x)
```

So my question is:

Can I compare the current row in the data set to each row in the group with referencing the current row value against each other row in the group?

I can join the data to each row and then run the comparison. But as I need many such comparisons, this will end up in many joins. So I'm expecting, that the functionality should be available out of the box. And yes, I could write my own aggregate function which would do the trick as well but as said, that should be part of the SQL standard?

A simple example would be:

```
drop table t;
CREATE TABLE t
(
    name  VARCHAR2(10)
  , num1   NUMBER
 , num2 number 
);

INSERT INTO t SELECT 'Hans',   1, 3 FROM DUAL;
INSERT INTO t SELECT 'Werner', 2, 5 FROM DUAL;
INSERT INTO t SELECT 'John',   1, 7 FROM DUAL;
INSERT INTO t SELECT 'Paul',   3, 4 FROM DUAL;
INSERT INTO t SELECT 'Fritz',  3, 3 FROM DUAL;

COMMIT;
SELECT t1.name
     , t1.num1
     , t1.num2
     , cnt
  FROM t t1
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
                              SELECT COUNT(1)     AS cnt
                                FROM t t2
                               WHERE t2.num1 <= t1.num1
                                     AND t2.num2 >= t1.num1
                          );
```

Comment: Could you provide some some sample data and desired output?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; an English explanation of a specific logic that you are trying to implement (not a problem that is so generic it is impossible to relate it to any specific logic); **YOUR** attempt at a solution to the specific problem; the issues/errors with your attempted solution; and the expected output for the sample data. At the moment your question is too generic and it is difficult to understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

> I would expect something like this (how often is the same data avaiable in the group):
>
> ```
> sum(case when current_row.dt = row.dt then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by x)
> ```

Don't use a `CASE` expression, just include `dt` in the `PARTITION BY` clause:

```
SUM(1) OVER (PARTITION BY x, dt)
```

or:

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY x, dt)
```

---

You cannot compare rows inside an analytic function; you will need to use a self-`JOIN` to compare rows.

> But as I need many such comparisons, this will end up in many joins.

If your problem is wanting to perform multiple aggregations then you can use a single `LATERAL` join and then use conditional aggregation so you only need to join once (rather than using one join for each calculation):

```sql
SELECT t1.name
     , t1.num1
     , t1.num2
     , t2.cnt1
     , t2.cnt2
     , t2.cnt3
FROM   t t1
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.num1 BETWEEN t2.num1 AND t2.num2 THEN 1 END) AS cnt1
              , COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.num1 >= t2.num1 THEN 1 END) AS cnt2
              , COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.num1 <= t2.num2 THEN 1 END) AS cnt3
         FROM   t t2
       ) t2;
```

Comment: See the example, it is not that straight forward

Comment: @Jörg You still need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78067474/edit) and explain what specific problem you are having issues with. If you are asking how to replace the `LATERAL JOIN` in your updated example with an analytic function, then you cannot - an analytic function doesn't do the same thing. If you are asking something else then you haven't explained what you want.